# Upgrading MVC project to .NET 4.5 seems to have broken the viewmodel in the view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

It worked before but now I get the error below.. HELP  ?

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<SAGE.College.SpeechOutliner.App.Models.Account.LogOnModel>" %>

   <%= Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName) %>
```

> Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'UserName' and no extension method 'UserName' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Just clean the solution and rebuild it.

Comment: Looks like you are missing the model reference in the beginning of the page.